# Find directories containing only zero-sized files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have about 2000 directories like this:

```
(0123)ABC45
(0124)DEF97
.....
(1253-1)XYZ_ZXY
....
```

There are directories containing files having a zero size as a result of unsuccessful extraction from archive. I need to find all these directories (or just numbers in brackets). My command to do this:

```
find . -type f -size 0 |cut -d')' -f 1 |cut -d'(' -f 2 |sort -u
```

But this command finds directories containing at least one zero-sized file, and I need directories where every file has a size of 0 bytes. How to do it?

Comment: Get all folders with at least one zero sized file, and then check that folder for files with positively sized files. If there is none, here is your victim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient (one invocation of `find` per sub-directory, plus one more to find all sub-directories) but this should work:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
    if [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +0c)" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$dir"
    fi
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
du -t -4K [Path]
```

Shows (sub-)folders with total size <= 4K (meaning empty or filled with 0-size files).